# Showing Qr code ngx-qrcode in ionic 5 error element not recognized

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, qr-code

I am trying to generate a Qr code and show It in the ionic component. I tried the following library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-qrcode2

But It seems to not recognize the element correctly. I have tried:

```
<ngx-qrcode 
      [qrc-value] = "value"
</ngx-qrcode>
```

[image: error]

And Also:

```
  <ngx-qrcode 
  [elementType]="elementType" 
  [value] = "value"
  cssClass = "aclass"
  errorCorrectionLevel = "L">
```

with the following error at run time:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
> Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-qrcode'.
>
> 1. If 'ngx-qrcode' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'ngx-qrcode' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>    to suppress this message.
> 3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. (" 
>    <ngx-qrcode [ERROR ->][value]="value">

I know This library is now deprecated, so I tried
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@techiediaries/ngx-qrcode

Similar results:

[image]

[image]

Library was imported in component module as following:

```
import { UbicacionPageRoutingModule } from './ubicacion-routing.module';

import { UbicacionPage } from './ubicacion.page';
import { UbicacionAltaComponent } from './ubicacion-alta/ubicacion-alta.component';
import { NgxQRCodeModule } from '@techiediaries/ngx-qrcode';
import { VerQrUbicacionModalComponent } from './ver-qr-ubicacion-modal/ver-qr-ubicacion-modal.component';

@NgModule({
  entryComponents: [UbicacionAltaComponent, VerQrUbicacionModalComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    UbicacionPageRoutingModule,
    NgxQRCodeModule
  ],
  declarations: [UbicacionPage, VerQrUbicacionModalComponent],
  exports: [ UbicacionAltaComponent, VerQrUbicacionModalComponent]
})
export class UbicacionPageModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. **Use ngx-qrcode** Instead of ngx-qrcode2 (It is deprecated)
2. Make sure you're imported in **App Module** and your **Component Module**

Answer (score 0):

"ngx-qrcode2" is deprecated, use ngx-qrcode instead.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@techiediaries/ngx-qrcode if you need a guide otherwise use https://github.com/techiediaries/ngx-qrcode if you prefer the git version